# Multiple pokemon go bugs

Tags: pokemon-go

I cannot find the fix for these problems (if there is one) anywhere. Basically whenever I start it up it gets stuck at the same spot on the loading screen (unless I've just reinstalled it) and it takes forever to load. If it does end up loading, nothing will load on the map. No pokestops, no gyms, it shows no pokemon nearby, and no pokemon encounters. The only time the app works is if I just reinstalled it, but it always ends up doing the same thing once I've closed the app. It also makes me log into my google account every single time. Is my game just fucked or is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is indicative of server issues rather than something on your end.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to say whether you're using Android or iOS, as they could be affected by different things.

I've had server issues numerous times with the game, but *every* time it has resulted in a cheerful screen saying, "Our servers are experiencing issues. Please come back later."

I *have* seen Ingress, their other game, come up once in a while with the map, but with no portals, links, or fields on it, indicating the app is getting data from Google Maps, but not the Ingress servers, but that's fairly unusual (since they check in with the server before they let you into the game); and in Ingress it can be remedied by quitting and restarting the app.

Comment: I'm using an iOS. It most likely is server issues because I've tried everything I can think of, and the only thing that remotely works is reinstalling the app. But once I quit the app the problems revert.